# Mathematics and the Peano Event, or the sign thereof

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics, badiou

One might say the Original Event in mathematics is Euclids axiomatisation of Plane Geometry.

Subsequent axiomatisation - such as Peanos Axioms for the natural numbers being an echo of that Event, and so not an Event as such, in itself. But merely an application of an already discovered idea - axiomatisation.

What are the nature of subsequent Events in mathematics?

One might pause here, and say why, given the natural numbers, did axiomatisation wait two millenia.

It surely isn't dependent on the difficulty of the task.

So, Peanos axioms is possibly then a sign of an Event.

Which one?

Comment: I imagine that the original mathematical event was the day some prehistoric hunter made marks in the sand, |||, to commemorate the three mastodons he killed. Surely Euclid is important, but his work is a relatively recent development.

Comment: @user4894: Sure, Counting came first, and then Arithmetic and Mensuration. But thats why I said Mathematics as it is commonly understood in discourse - ie with deduction and axiomatics. Counting got resurrected with Cantor but thats a story already well-told.

Comment: A question of genius or a [script](http://www.elsewhere.org/pomo/) run wild? Who can tell? :)

Comment: "But thats why I said Mathematics as it is commonly understood in discourse" -- Actually, you didn't say anything of the sort. Why are you posting garbage?

Comment: @user4894: yes, you're right; I didn't; but I did say 'Mathematics', and it is commonly understood that this includes *deduction* and *axiomatics*, which is exemplified in usual discourse by way of 'Euclids axiomatisation of Geometry'.

Comment: or are you disputing that? Thats why I didn't say arithmetic or counting which doesn't include either in the *formal* sense, but which does include *reasoning*; nor did I say mensuration, which is to geometry what arithmetic is to mathematics, ie just the measurement of areas and volumes without axioms or deduction, but again with reasoning. Does this amount to 'Garbage'? Or is the Garbage somewhere else in the question? Can you pin-point it a little further?

Comment: @Drux: the post-modern generator was pretty funny, when I came across it six years ago; Of course, its a conceptually simple job to pick an arbitrary mix of axioms and recursively output all its deductions, and with a judicious mix of added text spin that off as a kind of math-speak, that is in fact entirely correct, but which of course says nothing at all.

Comment: Or you can try [this](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/scigen/)!

Comment: @Mozibur Ullah I understand what you're saying! Thank you for your patience. Yes, I am disagreeing. I believe that the first mathematical event was when Og the Hunter killed a mastodon; and put down a mark in the dirt. And when he killed another mastodon, he put another mark next to the first. And when he was applying for the job of chief mastodon killer at his local cave, he pointed to his many marks in the dirt. That was the birth of mathematical abstraction. From that to the Peano axioms was just a matter of time. The first mathematical act was the correspondence between things and marks.

Comment: @user4894: Well, in one sense you are right - after all one shouldn't consider mathematics to have begun solely with Euclids axioms, but it is a *significant* event - which is why I was referring to it. Secondly why did the PA system take so long to develop? If think Addems answer below touches on the deeper *motivation* or *Event* for it - which it was part of  the programme of turning logic into mathematics; thinking through PA axioms is a simple exercise, so simple that it isn't actually worth doing it; for it to be worth doing it, it needed to be part of something larger. Its this question

Comment: of the motivation, the larger Event, that my question is alluding to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An important point to make is that, for a long time Mathematics was largely considered synonymous with Geometry--similar to how, today, there is a sense that Mathematics is essentially Algebra.  Of course, professionals would deny this, but among the public there is certainly this sense; and among professionals, there is a feeling that, if a system doesn't have a corresponding abstract, algebraic expression in terms of symbols that are written in lines of text, then it's quite mathematical--or that it gains greater status as mathematical, once it has an algebraic expression.  Since the ancients and medievals saw Mathematics as having Geometry as its core, they may not have thought there was so much that was interesting in axiomatizing numbers and other systems.  When Descartes showed that all Geometry can be expressed algebraically and vice versa, interest in Algebra grew dramatically, and perhaps in light of that, it "only" took a few centuries thereafter to axiomatize other systems.

This is a mere informed guess, which I suppose is all you could get in response to this question, short of a historical research project.

Comment: I would suggest also looking into the history of formalizing logic, since it was really this project that ultimately led to the set theory foundations of modern Mathematics.

Comment: Sure, that's the historical trajectory that I'm referring to implicitly. I'd say Descartes analytic geometry, thinking of the plane as composed directly of points in terms of coordinates leads very easily to higher dimensions - its easy to generalise from 3 coordinates to n coordinates in a way that isn't possible synthetically. Though, having achieved that insight analytically, people are busy or have been busy to develop the same tools synthetically.

Comment: Sure, that's the historical trajectory that I'm referring to implicitly. I'd say Descartes analytic geometry, thinking of the plane as composed directly of points in terms of coordinates leads very easily to higher dimensions - its easy to generalise from 3 coordinates to n coordinates in a way that isn't possible synthetically. Though, having achieved that insight analytically, people are busy or have been busy to develop the same tools synthetically, taking to heart the slogan 'coordinates are an act of vandamism'.

Comment: I think your cooment, rather than your answer, is on the right track, that its probably the programme (or 'Event'!) of turning logic into mathematics via set theory (that predated Hilberts actual formal enunciation of it) that prompted the axiomatisation of Arithmetic - ie Peanos Axioms.